# double chevrons in a vector gets misread?

Tags: c++

In the book Accelerated C++ it is stated that if you declare a vector of vectors like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> foo;
```

it can generate errors because the >> can be misread as an operator, so you are in fact supposed to write it like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > foo;
```

However, my code that uses these structures written the first way seems to work. Is this a modern convention that I should be following?

Comment: What compiler are you using? For MSVC this was fixed in Visual Studio 2008 so that either syntax works appropriately.

Comment: @AJG85: As Charles Bailey very correctly states, technically it would be more appropriate to say that it was *broken* in VS 2008. Now that we have a standard it is *fixed*.

Comment: @AJG85:  Visual C++ 2005 supported the unspaced right angle brackets as well.

Comment: I couldn't remember exactly, thus comment and not answer. A better point to make is to get a more recently printed book.

Comment: The current standard has made some very obscure corner case template instantiations that were legal, illegal. E.g. `my2< mytempl<64 >> 2> > a;` now needs to be `my2< mytempl<(64 >> 2)> > a;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of C++ (C++11) has made the first version legal. Some compilers have always accepted it (technically in error against C++03). The second version is safer and more widely compatible.

Comment: It is worth noting now that in C++11 if you want to execute a right-shift operation in the template parameter, you have to wrap it in parenthesis, thus `vector<something_taking_an_int<2>>3>> vx;` becomes `vector<something_taking_an_int<(2>>3)>> vx;`